# flex builder datagrids formatting

Tags: apache-flex, text, formatting, cell, datagrid

is there a way to control the text positioning in the datagrid cells in Flex so that all text in subsequent columns align on the same rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try an itemRenderer like this

```
<mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" vertical-align="middle">
  <mx:Label text="{data.text}"/>
</mx:HBox>
```

Your text will line up on the same [baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)) assuming it's all the same point size. Note that all columns will have to use the same itemRenderer, or one like it. I use that pattern a lot even for images, progress bars, etc.

Comment: That should work, but I dislike adding containers just for layout reasons. That's why Flex 4 separates Containers and Layouts into two things. Using containers for the pure reason of Layout makes the Flex app run slower.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these Label styles. These should work for most things:

```
textAlign="left|right|center"   
textDecoration="none|underline"    
textIndent="0"
```

Here is an example of its use an DataGridColumn's itemRenderer:

```
<mx:DataGrid>
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn>
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:Label width="100%" height="100%" textAlign="center"/>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Let me know if that helped! :)